# What are the ramifications of UNIX files and directories where owner doesn't have group rights to the file?

Tags: permissions, unix, files

I've a group of users, all of which are in a single group. Then I have a Java daemon that is a member of a seperate group.

I want both the users and the daemon to have access to the same set of files. Apparently, adding the daemon to a secondary group so that this works is not generally workable.

What if I give the daemon ownership of files and directories and the group of all users group rights? What sort of problems might I see? Is this bad for security?

Do different UNIX and Linux environments interpret this differently? This environment is Linux: Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (10.04) Server.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in such situations is much better to use `acl`. You need to install `acl` package and enable it in mount options. For example if /etc/fstab it looks like

```
/dev/mapper/server-home   /home    ext4    defaults,acl,noatime     0       2
```

You can manage right with `setfacl` command and check it with `getfacl`.

Comment: How do I know if the filesystem supports ACLs? I realize that ext2, ext3, and ext4 have mount options `acl` and `noacl`; what is the default? (man pages don't specify) Likewise, are ACLs supported on filesystems like XFS? I think that XFS and many others (JFS, btrfs) will probably support ACLs completely; is this right? Can Java (yes, I know Java comes in many kinds!) handle ACLs or is it transparent?

Comment: Oh - and you didn't answer my question :) Aside from "doing the right thing" (using ACLs from the sound of it) I'd also like to know how these permissions resolve themselves and how UNIX/Linux handles it.